# Differentiate between float and double in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

i am trying to extract constants from the LLVM IR for further analysis. So far i have been able to extract ints, floats and doubles by using the appropriate methods.

How can i differentiate between floats and doubles before trying to get the value from the methods in the APF class. Without an appropriate check i end up triggering an assert when i invoke `convertToFloat()` on a double or a `convertToDouble()` on a float. Is there some indirect mechanism in LLVM to distinguish between the datatypes before trying to get the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways, the simplest one I can think of is by using [the `getSemantics` method](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1APFloat.html#a4f9fe1ca06b44499c16742431c00cb34):

```cpp
bool IsFloat = MyFloat.getSemantics() == &APFloat::IEEEsingle;
bool IsDouble = MyFloat.getSemantics() == &APFloat::IEEEdouble;
```

By the way, it's more common to just check the type of the `Value` that the `APFloat` came from, if you have it:

```cpp
bool IsFloat = MyValue.getType()->isFloatTy();
bool IsDouble = MyValue.getType()->isDoubleTy();
```

Comment: Just verified. Both of them work work perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size of each type then you can use a substitute function for sizeof() of the C Language as described in this link:
http://nondot.org/sabre/LLVMNotes/SizeOf-OffsetOf-VariableSizedStructs.txt

Comment: Thanks. I think what i am trying to do is fairly trivial and there should be some in-built stuff that i could use. If there's nothing like that i guess what you pointed out is one solution to this.